Nullable strings in Midl 3.0
I am working on a Windows Runtime <-> Rust integration through windows-rs. The interface between the two languages is defined trough an .idl (Midl 3.0) file.
I am trying to declare a parameter as a nullable string.
The documentation specifies

For each non-nullable value type T (except String), there's a corresponding nullable type Windows.Foundation.IReference, which can hold the additional value null.

So it seems that for every value type (apart from String) I can use IReference for nullable and any reference type is nullable by default. Both of these would translate to an Option on the Rust side.
It seems that the only type1 that cannot be nullable is String. If you try IReference<String> you will get this MIDL error:

error MIDL5037 : [msg]Invalid parameter to IReference or IReferenceArray

If your parameter type is String, when you try to pass a null from C#, you'd get

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null


There is a workaround though, it's to create a struct (or a runtime class) wrapping a String:
struct OptionalString {
  String value;
};

Then you can do IReference<OptionalString>. This works because the rule is "any value type apart from String", and structs containing strings do not match the exception.

I can't wrap my head around why you can have any1 parameter as optional, excepted if it's a string. Is this a flaw of MIDL, or is it by design? Is there a way to accomplish this without a workaround?

1 I stand corrected, it's not only String. It looks like you cannot have nullable arrays either. If you use IReference<Type[]>, then you'll get a syntax error. But I believe nullable arrays are a less common use case (at least for me).

Strings aren't nullable because a null pointer represents an empty string. An alternative is to wrap the string in a Property value. Then you can use a null PropertyValue to represent the null state.

@RaymondChen By "wrap the string in a Property value" you mean declaring a struct containing a String like my "OptionalString" suggestion?

I mean accept an Object, and the caller passes null or a boxed string (represented at the ABI by a Windows.Foundation.PropertyValue object). More discussion: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20231215-00/?p=109155

Thanks for the link! I'd rather not accept an Object tough as I'd prefer my interface to be strongly typed.

Yeah, it's not a great solution. A struct wrapper would also work  The best way is to try to arrange it so that an empty string is not valid, so that you can use that as your null state.

The problem with considering empty string as a null is that you can't make it explicitly though your API which parameters are "nullable" and which ones are not. Sure you can still add comments in the idl, but it's not as obvious as reflecting directly in the signature. I'd always prefer to have the signature carrying most of the information.

I'm not saying it's the best solution in a perfect world. Just that it's the best solution within the framework of the Windows Runtime, which needs to accommodate multiple languages, and it's just a sad fact of life that different languages have different opinions about strings and nullability.
